# active status is disabled when creating individual zend navigaton pages

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following code:

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){ 
       $application = $e->getApplication();
       $em = $application->getEventManager();
       $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this,'setupNav'),10000);
    }

    public function setupNav($e)
    {
        $serviceLocator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $router = $serviceLocator->get('router');
        $page = \Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage::factory(array(
                'label' => 'Login',
                'route' => 'login', 
                'resource' => 'auth.auth.login'                                     
        ));         
        $page->setRouter($router);
        $page->set('type','user');
        $serviceLocator->get('navigation')->addPage($page); 
    }
}
```

The problem is that these pages i create dynamically dont ever get marked as status active when the route matches (and adds an `active class`). It works fine for the ones loaded with the `navigation container (the config navigation)` but for some reason when i dynamically add  `Mvc Pages` **the status does not become active for these navigation elements**